# Using MerchantSuite with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have project where the webportal uses MerchantSuite to process payments. Is it possible to integrate the MerchantSuite API in the mobile app version?

Comment: https://www.merchantsuite.com/site/world/Product/Details/API

Comment: does it require having to use a specific Nuget package like stripe does?

Comment: I have no idea.  I have never used it.  If you intend to use it you should start by reading their documentation.  It took me 30s to determine that they have a REST API and support C#.